# C# & SQL Server : update not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm writing some code which is meant to update data in my database, and for some reason I am getting this error when I press the update button:

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Here is my code, it's a duplicate of my `INSERT` statement which works perfectly so I am unsure why this isn't working.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   sqlCommand2.CommandText = @"UPDATE Personal_Details 
   SET Title = '" + comboBox1.Text.Trim() + "', FIRSTNAME = '" +Txt_FirstName.Text.Trim()+ "', MIDDLENAME = '" + mIDDLENAMETextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + sURNAMETextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + cITYTextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + eMAILTextBox.Text.Trim() + "' WHERE PersonID = '"+personIDTextBox+"'";
   sqlConnection1.Open();
   sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
   sqlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Comment: Well, the exception explains it *clearly*: it should be `sqlCommand2.Connection = sqlConnection1;` (before `sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();`)

Comment: Never concatenate input from text boxes to make a SQL query. Google SQL injection.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I don't understand, this code is exactly the same as my insert one, just with a different query. Yet it's throwing this error and my insert works perfect.

Comment: You sql is just wrong, where is your middlename field? Your Surname field? Your City field? etc etc

Comment: @PaulZahra I don't know what you're talking about, this uses data from textboxes and then sends the update command, my insert command is exactly the same and works fine

Comment: look at your sql string... e.g. mIDDLENAMETextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + sURNAMETextBox.Text.Trim() That should be mIDDLENAMETextBox.Text.Trim() + "', SURNAME = '" + sURNAMETextBox.Text.Trim() ...

Comment: @imamage597 I suggest you have a look into using https://stylecop.codeplex.com/

Comment: @imamage597 If you want an example of why your method (not using parameters) of inserting a record is bad (backup your database first) then type in the firstname textbox... fred'); DROP TABLE Personal_Details;-- then press 'submit' button and stand back and marvel at how you no longer have a Personal_Details table in your database :D Now go read up on sanitizing your sql query string and how parameterising your sql is a good thing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this line before calling ExecuteNonQuery

```
sqlCommand2.Connection = sqlConnection1;
```

A part from this I really suggest you to read about [Parameterized Queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) and [Using Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Well I tried adding that and now I get this:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: And then again - use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation -

Comment: Sorry but would you mind expanding? I am fairly new to this

Comment: Look at the answer below from Paul Zahra

Answer (score 1):

I needed a break from Windows Services so I did it for you... Expanding on Steve's answer... Now go read up why Parameterised queries are better than your approach (hint: security), and read up on what the using statement is doing for you (hint: closes and disposes the connection for you).

**EDITED:**

```
string mySql = @"UPDATE Personal_Details SET Title = @myTitle, FIRSTNAME = @myFirstName, MIDDLENAME = @myMiddleName, SURNAME = @mySurname, CITY = @myCity, EMAIL = @myEmail WHERE PersonID = @myPersonId";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mySql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myTitle", comboBox1.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myFirstName", Txt_FirstName.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myMiddleName", mIDDLENAMETextBox.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mySurname", sURNAMETextBox.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myCity", cITYTextBox.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myEmail", eMAILTextBox.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myPersonId", personIDTextBox.Text.Trim());

        conn.Open();

        int numberOfAffectedRows = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better use ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader. The query is executed but there is no sense in creating a DataReader when there is nothing to read

Comment: the command is missing the reference to a connection object ^^

Comment: @Steve lol I took that datareader method example from the link you gave :D

Answer (score 0):

There was no connection strings given in your side.

```
        var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(@"give your connection string here");
        SqlCommand  sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand();
        sqlCommand2.CommandText = @"update query";
        sqlCommand2.Connection = sqlConnection1;
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        sqlCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters for best results. But you can use the following way if you don't want to use parameters:-

```
        string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn ;
        SqlCommand cmd ;
        string sql = null;

        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
        sql = @"UPDATE Personal_Details 
    SET Title = '" + comboBox1.Text.Trim() + "', FIRSTNAME = '" +Txt_FirstName.Text.Trim()+ "', MIDDLENAME = '" + mIDDLENAMETextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + sURNAMETextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + cITYTextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + eMAILTextBox.Text.Trim() + "' WHERE PersonID = '"+personIDTextBox+"'";

        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error"); 
        }
```

Also add this at the top: `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: Using this replies "Error". I have corrected my SQL statement and put the connection string in correctly.